# Is there any benefit of using html5shim library  over document.createElement('header')?

Tags: javascript, html, shim

What is difference between using

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script>
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('footer');
  document.createElement('section');
  document.createElement('nav');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

instead

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The guy only asked a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the HTML shim library also includes the [IE print Protector](http://www.iecss.com/print-protector/)